# Embed Unlisted You Tube Channel into a WordPress Web Page

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I want to embed an unlisted channel with unlisted videos into a web page that displays each video as a thumbnail. When you click on the thumbnail it plays in page - or some variation of this.  What is the best and easiest way to accomplish this via free plugin or script?

Comment: Have you conducted any research into this enquiry? Please refer to [StackOverflow - Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for the correct way to ask questions specifically opinion based questions. There are plenty of results from a simple Google Search...

Comment: I would assume that such a comment would indicate that you confirmed my specific question was already answered.  In which case, providing a link to that answer would be more productive.  I did search and I did not find the answer.

Comment: No, in fact my comment related to the link I provided stating that your question does not show any evidence of research prior to your question. If you have done research you should state what attempts you have made to enable any member of the community to provide additional information which you may not have attempted. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in google found a couple of options.

Wordpress Legacy
https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-easily-embed-videos-in-wordpress-blog-posts/

Third-Party Plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/

Additional Reading/Options
https://kinsta.com/blog/embed-youtube-video-wordpress/

Comment: I'm looking for one that can display Unlisted you tube videos.  These are all great and easy if your videos are set to public.  I tested about 5 and none work with unlisted so far. Either way thanks and I guess I'll just delete the post since I have to defend it.